# Issue with COM Interop in C#

Tags: c#, com-interop

Hi i have an App where one of the jobs will be pick up all the records from an Excel file, and to do it i am using COM Interop.

So this works fine and it's doing what i really want. The problem is if we add the reference to the the library version 14.0 (Office 2010) in the Project but if we pick our App and if we run it in any PC with a different version of the Office 2010, he won't recognize the library because it have a different version(e. g. Office 2007 - versioan 12.0).

So it's any way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think if you use late binding and use the version independed progid.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to read the excel file outside of excel I advice using third party fully managed libraries like "Spreadsheet Gear" or "GemBox", they are faster and easier to work with. (there are open source xls parser and libraries for open xml xlsx format but I didn't tested them)

If you need to work inside excel, I know of only "Add-in Express" that provide version independent office interop dlls.

Comment: if this is a option, use the open xml sdk 2.0. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c6e744e5-36e9-45f5-8d8c-331df206e0d0&displaylang=en which is free and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to program against the oldest Office version you need to get supported. But actually, you can use any interop version to support as many Office versions as you need, see [Supporting several Office versions in an add-in. Interop assemblies and late binding.](http://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2010/03/16/interop-assemblies-late-binding/)